# Xamarin classes.jar used by other process

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am using VS 2013, Xamarin Android.
I can not compile / build my project because I get every time the error message "Error  6   The process cannot access the file 'classes.jar' because it is being used by another process.   App1" App1 is my project name.
I only run VS2013.

Thanks

Comment: Open Task Scheduler and check if there are any process related to App1. Also try killing Xamarin process.

Comment: Thanks, but I could nothing find.

Comment: Did you try killing all the process related to VS 2013? You definitely have some application using the .jar file in some way. There is a tool to find out the process which locked your file- http://superuser.com/questions/117902/find-out-which-process-is-locking-a-file-or-folder-in-windows

Comment: Good idea but it only shows me one file and that is exactly that the application is using.